# Three conditions in query

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is working query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool":
    { "must_not":{"exists":{"field":"ParentId"}},
      "should":[
        {"query_string":{"default_field":"Name","query":"*es*"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get the documents with `ParentId=null` and `Name` containing `es` substring.

I need to add another one condition filter by substring of another field:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool":
    { "must_not":{"exists":{"field":"ParentId"}},
      "should":[
        {"query_string":{"default_field":"Name","query":"*ewr*"}},
        {"wildcard":{"OrganizationPath":{"wildcard":"1_6_32*"}}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now the filter by `Name` stops working.

Another try with the same result:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool":
    { "must_not":{"exists":{"field":"ParentId"}},
      "should":[
        {"query_string":{"default_field":"Name","query":"*ewr*"}},
        {"query_string":{"default_field":"OrganizationPath", "query": "1_6_32*"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Why and how I can fix it ?

Comment: Replace `should` with `filter`

Comment: Thanks, it works.And `must` works fine.

Comment: yes, `must` or `filter` would work, just use `filter` if you don't need scoring but just yes/no matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want all your constraints to match you need to replace `should` with `filter`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool":
    { "must_not":{"exists":{"field":"ParentId"}},
      "filter":[
        {"query_string":{"default_field":"Name","query":"*ewr*"}},
        {"query_string":{"default_field":"OrganizationPath", "query": "1_6_32*"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that if you need scoring you can use `must` instead of `filter`, otherwise `filter` works just fine for your need.